# Is it possible to add a property to properties.AfterProperties of ItemAdding from NewForm?

Tags: 2013, development, event-receivers, custom-form

I'm working on a legacy code and I'm not supposed to refactor it too much.

There is a part where from `ItemAdding` and `ItemUpdating` Event Receiver I need to know the information that is available on the New Form.

The first thing that comes to my mind is `properties.AfterProperties` because it's already used in the Event Receiver.

But is it even possible to use New Form somehow to make a new property to appear in `properties.AfterProperties` without adding a new field to list to which Event Receiver is attached?

Answer (score 0):

I was forced to add a new field in list schema to be able to use it in the Event Receiver - I couldn't find any other solution.